# gulp. style.min.css в product, а style.css в dev

Tags: gulp, scss, gulp-sass

Подскажие по gulp (я не очень разбираюсь). Итак в результате сборки и компиляции sass и в продакт и дев версиях я получаю 2файла сss и min.css. Что если я не хочу в продакт версии получать обычный css а только min.css а в дев версии хочу получать наоборот Только обычный css. Подскажите как это настроить. Как я понимаю сначала генерируется оыбчный файл и за счет cleanCSS происходит минификация. Наверно эти плагины можно настроить чере gulp-if . Но что писать внутри какой код ?
или просто подскажите как удалять сss или min.css если в результате получаю оба.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, просто в функции было два одинаковых pipe , к одному из которых применялся clean. Поэтому я и получал 2 разных файла css .